# Site-2-Site between 2 Azure VNETs

Tags: azure-virtual-network, ipsec

Configuring a **VNet-to-VNet** connection is the preferred option to easily connect VNets if you need a secure tunnel using IPsec/IKE. In this case the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vnet-vnet-rm-ps#site-to-site-ipsec) says that traffic between VNets is routed through the Microsoft backbone infrastructure.

According to the documentation, a **Site-to-Site** connection is also possible:

> If you are working with a complicated network configuration, you may prefer to connect your VNets using the Site-to-Site steps, instead the VNet-to-VNet steps. When you use the Site-to-Site steps, you create and configure the local network gateways manually.

In this case we have control over the configuration of the virtual local network address space, but we need expose public IPs. Documentation don´t says nothing about where the traffic goes (azure internal or public internet)

My question is, in this scenario, S2S between VNets, the traffic is routed through azure infrastructure as in the case of VNet-to-VNet or the comunication is done through public internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### edit

The traffic in an S2S between VNets is routed through Microsoft backbone network. See [this do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/microsoft-global-network#our-network-is-your-network)c.

> Microsoft Azure offers the richest portfolio of services and
>   capabilities, allowing customers to quickly and easily build, expand,
>   and meet networking requirements anywhere. Our family of connectivity
>   services span virtual network peering between regions, hybrid, and
>   in-cloud point-to-site and site-to-site architectures as well as
>   global IP transit scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You detail two scenarios, VNet to on-premise S2S, and VNet to VNet connection. Both are well documented. I´m asking about **S2S between two VNets** as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vnet-vnet-rm-ps#site-to-site-ipsec).

Comment: The suggested site to site specifies VNet to on-premise S2S. In Azure, you just could use Vnet to Vnet connection(in this case, you actually need to create two VPN gateways) or VNet peerings to connect between VNets. What you think site to site between azure VNets is just to use VNet to VNet connection.

Comment: Hi Nancy. Have you take a look to my first link? You can also connect VNets with S2S connection. Moreover, there are scenarios in which VNet to VNet is not allowed, for example connecting VNets in separate Azure instances. In this [cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal#can-i-use-vnet-to-vnet-to-connect-virtual-networks-in-separate-azure-instances) S2S between VNets is the only way to have a encrypting tunnel between VNets.

Comment: Anyway, the question is not about the different ways of connecting VNets, the question is if the traffic in a S2S between VNets is routed through Microsoft backbone and if it is private or not.

Comment: The traffic between Azure VNets should be through the Azure backbone network. See my edited link.

Comment: Thanks. Also from MSFT [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-network-security/): "Azure traffic between our datacenters stays on our global network and does not flow over the Internet. This includes all traffic between Microsoft Azure public cloud services anywhere in the world. "